# security through cloud code in Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

Is it possible to use cloud code to enforce security (access control) in an application in Parse? Has anyone tried this earlier?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do. It is possible to enforce certain controls in Cloud to prevent Create, Update and Delete operations on Parse Classes by simply returning `response.error` in your `beforSave` trigger functions. However if you want to restrict Read access to your data, you must rely on ACL permissions and CLPs.